# DOS Batch File: Search for a Variable in a variable

Tags: variables, search, batch-file

I have 2 Variables namely DOW and RxDow where %DOW% is 'Fri' (Current Day of the Week) and %RxDow% is 'Mon,Wed,Fri,' (Designated Days of the Week)

when I try to use the following command it does not work

```
find /f %DOW% in %RxDow% do (echo exec spreindexusertables >> back.sql)
```

It says

> in was unexpected at this time.

I need a command that will search %DOW% in %RxDOW% and, if found, echo the required command to back.sql. Please help.

Regards,

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? On Windows 8.1 /F is not a valid switch for Find. Are you actually using FOR? If so, please post your *precise* code...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to write exec spreindexusertables to back.sql if the day is a weekday. Correct? If so, the following should get you there:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "dow=Fri"
set "RxDow=Mon,Tues,Weds,Thurs,Fri"

 for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%a in ('echo %RxDow%^|Find /i "%dow%"') do (echo exec spreindexusertables >> back.sql)
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly and got the exact results I required. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You may do that trying to delete `%DOW%` value from `%RxDOW%` variable; if the result is *different* than the original `%RxDOW%` variable, then `%DOW%` is in there. This method does not require any external command, like `find.exe`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "DOW=Fri"
set "RxDow=Mon,Wed,Fri"

if  "!RxDow:%DOW%=!" neq "%RxDow%" echo exec spreindexusertables >> back.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Using && operator that executes the second command is the first one has no error.

```
set "dow=Mon"
set "RxDow=Mon,Tues,Weds,Thurs,Fri"

(echo %RxDow% | find "%dow%">nul) && (echo exec spreindexusertables >> back.sql)
```